# Examples of Talagrand's inequality

Tags: probability, self-learning

I am trying to understand [Talagrand's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talagrand%27s_concentration_inequality) and when it gives better results than Markov/Chebyshev/Chernoff.  However I find the formal definition hard to understand. Are there any nice simple examples using discrete random variables that shows its purpose?

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~nickcook/talagrand.pdf This link may help.